# How would we explain meteorological phenomena in an inertial reference frame?

Tags: reference-frames, meteorology, coriolis-effect

The Coriolis effect is used to explain the formation of typhoons, hurricanes, and cyclones and other phenomena where we take the Earth as a rotating reference frame. How could we explain this phenomena in an inertial reference frame?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Disclaimer: borrowed from wikipedia with minor modifications.

The acceleration is the second time derivative of position, 
$$ 
\mathbf{a}_{\mathrm{i}} \ \stackrel{\mathrm{ }}{=}\   
\left( \frac{d^{2}\mathbf{r}}{dt^{2}}\right)_{\mathrm{i}} = 
\left( \frac{d\mathbf{v}}{dt} \right)_{\mathrm{i}} = 
\left[  \left( \frac{d}{dt} \right)_{\mathrm{r}} + 
\boldsymbol\Omega \times 
\right]
\left[
\left( \frac{d\mathbf{r}}{dt} \right)_{\mathrm{r}} + 
\boldsymbol\Omega \times \mathbf{r} 
\right] \ ,$$
where subscript $i$ means the inertial frame of reference. Carrying out the differentiations and re-arranging some terms yields the acceleration in the rotating reference frame
 $$
\mathbf{a}_{\mathrm{r}} = 
\mathbf{a}_{\mathrm{i}} - 
2 \boldsymbol\Omega \times \mathbf{v}_{\mathrm{r}} - 
\boldsymbol\Omega \times (\boldsymbol\Omega \times \mathbf{r}) - 
\frac{d\boldsymbol\Omega}{dt} \times \mathbf{r}
$$ where $$\mathbf{a}_{\mathrm{r}} \ \stackrel{\mathrm{}}{=}\   \left( \frac{d^{2}\mathbf{r}}{dt^{2}} \right)_{\mathrm{r}} $$ is the apparent acceleration in the rotating reference frame, the term $$-\boldsymbol\Omega \times (\boldsymbol\Omega \times \mathbf{r})$$ represents centrifugal acceleration, and the term $$-2 \boldsymbol\Omega \times \mathbf{v}_{\mathrm{r}}$$ is the coriolis acceleration.

When the expression for acceleration is multiplied by the mass of the particle, the three extra terms on the right-hand side result in fictitious forces in the rotating reference frame, that is, apparent forces that result from being in a non-inertial reference frame, rather than from any physical interaction between bodies.
Using Newton's second law of motion $\mathbf{F}=m\mathbf{a}$, we obtain:

the Coriolis force

$$\mathbf{F}_{\mathrm{Coriolis}} = 
-2m \boldsymbol\Omega \times \mathbf{v}_{\mathrm{r}}$$

the centrifugal force

$$\mathbf{F}_{\mathrm{centrifugal}} = 
-m\boldsymbol\Omega \times (\boldsymbol\Omega \times \mathbf{r})$$
and 
the Euler force

$$\mathbf{F}_{\mathrm{Euler}} = 
-m\frac{d\boldsymbol\Omega}{dt} \times \mathbf{r}$$
where $m$ is the mass of the object being acted upon by these fictitious forces.

Comment: I should've remembered that equation, I just read it yesterday.

Comment: Take it easy, I usually forget much more basic things :)